# SQL Query on 2 meta keys from Woocommerce Order itemmeta table

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I currently have a sql query to call all order id's of a specific product type but I now need it to just call orders that also have a specific meta key, the value of this key increases with each bought item just as long as it has one.

```
function get_last_order_id_from_product( $product_id ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT order_items.order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
        WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_value = '$product_id'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_key = 'Ticket Number'
        ORDER BY order_items.order_id DESC LIMIT 1, 1
    ");

    return $results;
}
```

I assumed that as it was already calling a meta key using the same call variable would work but it just gives me an internal server error in woocommerce when the function is called. The meta Key in question is

```
AND order_item_meta.meta_key = 'Ticket Number'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **`JOIN`** another time the table `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`  with its own reference, **as you are querying 2 times a different meta keys on that table**, so try instead the following:

```
function get_last_order_id_from_product( $product_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT oi.order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as oi
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as oim
            ON oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as oim2
            ON oi.order_item_id = oim2.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS p
            ON oi.order_id = p.ID
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND oi.order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND oim.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND oim.meta_value = '%d'
        AND oim2.meta_key = 'Ticket Number'
        ORDER BY oi.order_id DESC
        LIMIT 1, 1
    ", $product_id ) );
}
```

Tested and works.